# How to prove semigroup of linear operators is bounded dissipative?

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Suppose ${\lbrace T(t)\rbrace}_{t \ge 0} $ be a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) of operators on some Banach space $X$. How to prove semigroup $ T(t) $ is bounded dissipative ? Here bounded dissipative means, there exist a bounded set $B$ in $X$ which attract every bounded set of $X$ under $T(t) \quad \text{i.e} \quad \text{ dist}(T(t) \tilde{B}, B) \rightarrow 0$ as $ t \rightarrow \infty$ for every bounded set $\tilde{B}$ in $X$. I am following the book of [Jack K. Hale](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=D5EF50EDFE261F99E04B2363DCBBA047) for study of dissipative systems. I am not finding any example in this book for this purpose. 
For $\alpha >0$, suppose our semigroup is $\text{e}^{-\alpha t}T(t)$ , where $T(t)$ is the semigroup generated by Dirichlet laplacian in $L^{2}(0,1)$. For this how we will proceed.

Comment: Usually the answer depends a lot on the properties of the semigroup (for example, for which type of problem it comes, hopefully with some kind of compactness property). Since you say nothing about that, it is really impossible to give you any reasonable answer.

Comment: @JohnB, I have edited my question. I just want a feel to the procedure of proving dissipativeness of semigroup. Please also give some references where I can find some examples.